# Build a MU puzzle solver

Tags: code-golf, puzzle-solver

The [MU puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle) is a puzzle in which you find out whether you can turn `MI` into `MU` given the following operations:

1. If your string ends in `I`, you may add a `U` to the end. (e.g. `MI -> MIU`)
2. If your string begins with `M`, you may append a copy of the part after `M` to the string.
   (e.g. `MII -> MIIII`)
3. If your string contains three consecutive `I`'s, you may change them into a `U`.
   (e.g. `MIII -> MU`)
4. If your string contains two consecutive `U`'s, you may delete them. (e.g. `MUUU -> MU`).

Your task is to build a program that determines whether this is doable for any start and finish strings.

Your program will take two strings as input. Each string will consist of the following:

- one `M`.
- a string of up to twenty-nine `I`'s and `U`'s.

Your program will then return `true` (or your programming language's representation thereof/YPLRT) if the second string is reachable from the first string, and `false` (or YPLRT) if it is not.

Example inputs and outputs:

```
MI  MII
true

MI  MU
false

MIIIIU  MI
true
```

The shortest code in any language to do this wins.

Comment: I'm currently reading Gödel, Escher, Bach and thought about doing an "18-hole golf course"based on its chapters afterwards. Guess I've got to find a new "hole 1" now. ;)

Comment: This is just a graph reachability question whose essence has been asked plenty of times before.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think there's a good chance this won't be solved by an explicit search of the reachability graph. The MIU rules have a lot of structure, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's a direct algorithm to test for reachability without searching for intermediate nodes. For example, the nodes reachable from `MI` are exactly the `M(I|U)*` where the number of `I` isn't a multiple of 3. And such a direct check surely makes for shorter code. Also, I don't know of an a-priori bound on the lengths of strings required for intermediate steps, so direct search might be simply impractical.

Comment: @xnor, on the other hand it's an instance of a Turing-complete system, so explicit search of the reachability graph may be the only approach that works in the general case.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, it's Turing complete? I don't remember that from GEB. Can you please point me to a proof?

Comment: @xnor, I said "*an instance of a Turing-complete system*". Specifically, it's a [Post canonical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, I see. I guess then the question remains whether there's a problem-specific method. I haven't found one but I hope someone will.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I understand what you mean about the reachability graph, but as xnor said, I'm looking to see whether there are any solutions that are shorter that do something else.

Comment: I've thought about this problem for a while and haven't gotten close to a solution that isn't brute-force. If nobody bites, I suggest posting an easier version of the question, perhaps to give a derivation starting from `MI` of a given reachable string.

Comment: "The puzzle's solution is no. It is impossible to change the string MI into MU by repeatedly applying the given rules." So the program returns false whatever the input?

Comment: No, the program's input isn't just for MI to MU. I could be from MIIIIUIUIUIUUIUIUUIUU to MUIUUUIUIUUUIIIIIUIUI, for instance.

Comment: What should the output be if `IM` is supplied or `MUMMI`?

Comment: You can assume that input will be valid.

Comment: Since both start and end strings can be up to 30 characters, is there a limit on the length of a required intermediate string? For example, could a starting string of length 30 require being doubled a couple times right away to reach the ending string (thus reaching length 120)?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a limit on that.

Answer (score 8):

## SWI Prolog, 183 characters

```
m(A,A).
m([i],[i,u]).
m([i,i,i|T],B):-m([u|T],B).
m([u,u|T],B):-m(T,B).
n([m|A],[m|B]):-(m(A,B);append(A,A,X),m(X,B)).
n(A,B):-m(A,B).
s(A,B):-atom_chars(A,X),atom_chars(B,Y),n(X,Y).
```

How about some Prolog, (since nobody has answered in 6 months).
To run, just use "s(mi,mu)."  The code breaks up atoms into chars, then searches for the solution.

Comment: This wrongfully returns false on `s(mi,miiii)`, and in general anything requiring more than one application of rule 2 to prove.